# Anti-commutator relation of supercharges

Tags: special-relativity, supersymmetry, representation-theory, spinors, majorana-fermions

Reading mutiple references on SUSY (e.g. *Baer and Tata's Weak Scale SUSY* and *A SUSY Primer by S.P. Martin*, [arXiv:hep-ph/9709356](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9709356)), there seems to be different anti-commutation relation conventions for supercharges $Q_{\alpha}$.

Baer and Tata (Page 47 4.4. The supersymmetric algebra) follow: 
$$ 
\{ Q_a, Q_b \} ~=~ -2 ( \gamma^{\mu} C)_{ab}P_{\mu}, \tag{4.4.11g}
$$
whereas S.P. Martin (Eq. (3.1.31) on page 21) defines:
$$ 
\{ Q_{\alpha}, Q_{\beta} \} ~=~ 0.\tag{3.1.31}
$$

What could be the reason for these different conventions or definitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eq. (4.4.11g) is for a [Majorana spinor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorana_equation) SUSY charges $Q_a$, $a=1,2,3,4$, while eq. (3.1.31) is for left [Weyl spinor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_equation) SUSY charges $Q_{\alpha}$, $\alpha=1,2$.